# What is most efficient way to write from kafka to hdfs with files partitioning into dates

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-kafka

I'm working on project that should write via kafka to hdfs.
Suppose there is online server that writes messages into the kafka. Each message includes timestamp in it. 
 I want to create a job that the output will be a file/files according to timestamp in messages. 
For example if the data in kafka is

```
 {"ts":"01-07-2013 15:25:35.994", "data": ...}
 ...    
 {"ts":"01-07-2013 16:25:35.994", "data": ...}
 ... 
 {"ts":"01-07-2013 17:25:35.994", "data": ...}
```

I would like to get the 3 files as output

```
  kafka_file_2013-07-01_15.json
  kafka_file_2013-07-01_16.json
  kafka_file_2013-07-01_17.json
```

And of course If I'm running this job once again and there is a new messages in queue like

```
 {"ts":"01-07-2013 17:25:35.994", "data": ...}
```

It should create a file

```
  kafka_file_2013-07-01_17_2.json // second  chunk of hour 17
```

I've seen some open sources but most of them reads from kafka to some hdfs folder.
What is the best solution/design/opensource for this problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should definitely check out `Camus API` implementation from linkedIn. Camus is LinkedIn’s Kafka->HDFS pipeline. It is a mapreduce job that does distributed data loads out of Kafka. Check out this [post](http://saurzcode.in/2015/02/integrate-kafka-hdfs-using-camus-twitter-stream-example/) I have written for a simple example which fetches from twitter stream and writes to HDFS based on tweet timestamps.

Project is available at github at - https://github.com/linkedin/camus

Camus needs two main components for reading and decoding data from Kafka and writing data to HDFS –

### Decoding Messages read from Kafka

Camus has a set of Decoders which helps in decoding messages coming from Kafka,  Decoders basically extends `com.linkedin.camus.coders.MessageDecoder` which implements logic to partition data based on timestamp. A set of predefined Decoders are present in this directory and you can write  your own based on these.                                                                          `camus/camus-kafka-coders/src/main/java/com/linkedin/camus/etl/kafka/coders/`

### Writing messages to HDFS

Camus needs a set of RecordWriterProvider classes  which extends `com.linkedin.camus.etl.RecordWriterProvider` that will tell Camus what’s the payload that should be written to HDFS.A set of predefined RecordWriterProvider are present in this directory and you can write your own based on these.

```
camus-etl-kafka/src/main/java/com/linkedin/camus/etl/kafka/common
```

Comment: Camus has been retired by linkedin with gobblin. [for details](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2016/04/gobblin-gobbles-camus--looks-towards-the-future)

Comment: Goblin docs: http://gobblin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Goblin source: https://github.com/linkedin/gobblin

Comment: Here is an example with Gobblin. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GOBBLIN/Kafka-HDFS-Ingestion

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a more real-time approach you should check out [StreamSets Data Collector](http://streamsets.com). It's also an Apache licensed open source tool for ingest.

The HDFS destination is configurable to write to time based directories based on the template you specify. And it already includes a way to specify a field in your incoming messages to use to determine the time a message should be written. The config is called "Time Basis" and you can specify something like `${record:value("/ts")}`.

*full disclosure I'm an engineer working on this tool.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using Apache Kafka 0.9 or above, you can use the Kafka Connect API.

check out https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs

This is a Kafka connector for copying data between Kafka and HDFS.

Comment: _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._

Comment: This connect HDFS writer does not yet support writing json files

Answer (score 1):

Check this out for continuous ingestion from Kafka to HDFS. Since it depends on [Apache Apex](http://apex.apache.org/), it has the guarantees Apex provides.

https://www.datatorrent.com/apphub/kafka-to-hdfs-sync/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Camus:
https://github.com/linkedin/camus

This will write data in Avro format though... others RecordWriters are pluggable.