# Which is the most recommended way to copy all data from a Kafka topic to a sink (either a file or a Hive table)?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-kafka, hdfs, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using the Kafka Consumer API to copy all the data from a Kafka Topic to a Hive table. In order to do this I use HDFS as an intermediate step. I use an unique Group ID and reset the offset to "earliest" in order to get all the data from the beginning and ignore commits after execution. I then iterate over the records in the Kafka Topic and I save each record into a temporary file in HDFS. Then I use Spark to read the data from HDFS and I save it to a Parquet file using the date as the name of the file.
I then create a partition with the date in a Hive table and finally load the file in Parquet as a partition in Hive.

As you can see in the code below, I'm using several intermediate steps, which makes my code far from optimal. Is this the most recommended way to copy all the data from a Kafka Topic? I've done some research and so far this was the workaround I managed to get to work, however, as amount of records increase every day, my execution time is reaching the limit of the tolerable (gone from 20 minutes to 6 hours in 2 weeks).

The code is here:

```
def start( lowerDate: String, upperDate: String )={

    // Configurations for kafka consumer
    val conf = ConfigFactory.parseResources("properties.conf")
    val brokersip = conf.getString("enrichment.brokers.value")
    val topics_in = conf.getString("enrichment.topics_in.value")

    // Crea la sesion de Spark
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("yarn")
      .appName("ParaTiUserXY")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    import spark.implicits._

    val properties = new Properties
    properties.put("key.deserializer", classOf[StringDeserializer])
    properties.put("value.deserializer", classOf[StringDeserializer])
    properties.put("bootstrap.servers", brokersip)
    properties.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
    properties.put("group.id", "ParaTiUserXYZZ12345")


    //Schema para transformar los valores del topico de Kafka a JSON
    val my_schema = new StructType()
        .add("longitudCliente", StringType)
        .add("latitudCliente", StringType)
        .add("dni", StringType)
        .add("alias", StringType)
        .add("segmentoCliente", StringType)
        .add("timestampCliente", StringType)
        .add("dateCliente", StringType)
        .add("timeCliente", StringType)
        .add("tokenCliente", StringType)
        .add("telefonoCliente", StringType)

    val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](properties)
    consumer.subscribe( util.Collections.singletonList("parati_rt_geoevents")   )

    val fs = {
      val conf = new Configuration()
      FileSystem.get(conf)
    }


    val temp_path:Path = new Path("hdfs:///tmp/s70956/tmpstgtopics")
    if( fs.exists(temp_path)){
      fs.delete(temp_path, true)
    }

    while(true)
    {
        val records=consumer.poll(100)
        for (record<-records.asScala){
            val data = record.value.toString
            //println(data)
            val dataos: FSDataOutputStream = fs.create(temp_path)
            val bw: BufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(dataos, "UTF-8"))
            bw.append(data)
            bw.close
            val data_schema = spark.read.schema(my_schema).json("hdfs:///tmp/s70956/tmpstgtopics")
            val fechaCliente = data_schema.select("dateCliente").first.getString(0)

            if( fechaCliente < upperDate && fechaCliente >= lowerDate){
                data_schema.select("longitudCliente", "latitudCliente","dni", "alias", 
                "segmentoCliente", "timestampCliente", "dateCliente", "timeCliente",
                "tokenCliente", "telefonoCliente")
                   .coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet("/desa/landing/parati/xyuser/" + fechaCliente)

            }
            else if( fechaCliente < lowerDate){
                //
            }
            else if( fechaCliente >= upperDate){
              break;
            }

        }
   }

      consumer.close()

}
```

Comment: Your question is too much verbose. Could you please make it point wise? By the time i reached 2nd paragraph I lost the context.

Comment: How to copy the data in a Kafka Topic from the absolut beginning to a file or table.

Comment: A better solution would be to use Kafka Connect. If this would be acceptable let me know and I will post an answer with details.

Comment: Sure. That's anotherone of the Kafka APIs, right? If it's not tied to a particular vendor, it's certainly suitable.

Comment: You can checkout this question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/17426771/2444394